# Why is PostgreSQL statement failing on an apostrophe, when the syntax appears correct?

Tags: sql, bash, postgresql, syntax-error, postgresql-11

I wonderred if anybody has experienced an issue where PostgreSQL takes exception to a single apostrophe? I'm executing my PostgreSQL statement from the linux command line in order to copy data from a csv file into a table.

The table is already created and the file is in the correct directory, with correct permissions, ownership and name.

The top syntax is incorrect, whereas the bottom, which looks identical is correct.

```
--This line errors.
\copy nyc_addresses from '/home/postgres/city_of_new_york.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER);
--This line executes successfully.
\copy nyc_addresses from '/home/postgres/city_of_new_york.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER);
```

Through trial and error, we've managed to establish that the first apostrophe, in the top line of code is the issue, but cannot figure out quite why.

If it helps the error displayed is:

```
/home/postgres/city_of_new_york.csv: No such file or directory
```

Can anybody explain what may be the cause of this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Is postgres in the same machine as the client?

Comment: It's not a syntax error. It is a hint, that file `/home/postgres/city_of_new_york.csv` is not accessible by postgres.

Comment: Hi Jim, yes it's the same machine. Wiimm, the file is accessible, as the statement on the second line works. As mentioned we've managed to identify the first apostrophe in the first line being the cause of the statement to fail.

Comment: Can you try this from your console? `cat /home/postgres/city_of_new_york.csv | psql -U youruser -d yourdb -c "COPY nyc_addresses FROM STDIN"`

Comment: ```ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "LON,LAT,NUMBER,STREET,UNIT,POSTCODE,ID"
CONTEXT:  COPY nyc_addresses, line 1, column longitude: "LON,LAT,NUMBER,STREET,UNIT,POSTCODE,ID"```

Comment: Apologies my mistake - result has been successful. ```COPY 940374
``` Executed as follows ```cat /home/postgres/city_of_new_york.csv | psql -U postgres -d nyc_data -c "COPY nyc_addresses FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER)"```

Comment: I appreicate it but it doesn't resolve the query - the query worked with the second line in the initial description but not the first. The issue is the first apostrophe in the first line, but I have no idea why. That's what I'm trying to understand.

Comment: Can you `hexdump -C` the original file with those 2 lines to see if there is something that does not belong there?

Comment: @CharlesArthur I see, sorry.. I misunderstood the issue. Can add this first line to the question?

Comment: @JamesBrown there's no difference beteween the 2 lines but thanks I'll remember this.

Comment: @Jim Jones I've amended the question slightly, does this help?

Comment: No difference -> no issue.

Comment: @JamesBrown The top line still errors, whereas the second executes, depsite there being no obvious differences between the syntax. There's no issue in the fact it has worked on the second line, however, I wish to understand why the top line won't execute due to that first apotrophe, there must be an explanation for it.

Comment: @CharlesArthur I fail to see how the same command in this can have two different outputs. Are these commands a part of a bigger script?

Comment: @JimJones They're single statements, which I've executed independantly of one another, directly from psql.

Comment: @CharlesArthur this is really puzzling. The only option I have left would be that before you executed the first line there were an unterminated command (without `;`) and it is messing up the first copy. And since the first copy ends with a `;` the second one has a "fresh start". Could you log out `\q` and log in, and try it again?

Comment: @JimJones I've logged out and logged back in, used ctrl+c and successfully imported the data and truncated the table. I've made sure there aren't any incomplete statments that may interfere with the command and it still has an issue with it. It's completely bizarre.

Comment: And you run those two commands from a file `psql -f file ...` or do you type those in `psql`console and first one fails to work and second one works?

Comment: @CharlesArthur In this case I'm totally out of ideas :D As file and database are in the same machine, consider using `COPY` instead of `\COPY`.

Comment: @JamesBrown I run each statement from the ```psql``` console.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `COPY` csv files to PostgreSQL is to `cat` and pipe them to a `COPY` command `FROM STDIN`. This approach works no matter whether the database is installed locally or in a remote server.

```
$ cat file.csv | psql -U user -d db -c "COPY table FROM STDIN CSV HEADER"
```

**EDIT**: As pointed out by Nick Barnes (see comments) `cat` obviously needs to have the same permissions as `\copy`, which does not solve the mysterious OP issue.

@Jetchisel suggested the following alternative, which has the same effect of `cat` but might be more intuitive to some users:

```
psql -U user -d db -c "COPY table FROM STDIN CSV HEADER" < file.csv
```

Comment: `\copy` reads from client-side files, this isn't going to help with a permissions issue

Comment: @NickBarnes I'm not using `\copy`, but sending the file content to `psql` and using the standard input from `copy` (not `\copy`) :)

Comment: The example in the question is using `\copy`. If `\copy` doesn't have permission to read the file, then `cat` doesn't have permission to read the file.

Comment: @NickBarnes ahhh of course.. silly me. I'll edit my answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: `psql -U user -d db -c "COPY table FROM STDIN CSV HEADER" < file.csv` will work too?

Comment: @Jetchisel yes, it has the same effect :)